# Get attribute name without array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, attributes

I use PHP, I want to check if there is a name attribute and if thats is an array or an array with multiple levels,for example:

```
name="hello"
name="hello[]"
name="hello[1]"
name="hello[1][2]"
```

etc

I want to get hello and the array after it seperated and returned in an array i think:

```
array(hello,'')
array(hello,[])
array(hello,[1])
array(hello,[1][2])
```

something like that, so I can glue them back together or use seperatly later on

I think it must be done with regular expressions but how ?

Comment: What language? It looks like PHP? From the [tag:regex] tag: "*Remember to include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.*".

Comment: `/^([^[]+)(.*)$/` will give an array that includes the `hello` part, and the `[1][2]` part.

Answer (score 0):

Split on:

```
(?<!\])(?=\[)
```

This would split on the first `[` character before which no `]` character is encountered. eg.

```
$keywords = preg_split("/(?<!\])(?=\[)/", "hello[1][2]");
print_r($keywords);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => [1][2]
)
```